# Reportviewer re-sorts dataset?

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I am passing an entity framework dataset to an RDLC and the output is not in the order I expect.  Below is my code, and I am expecting the output to be sorted by the CarName column, but it is not rendered in that order.  What am I missing?

```
               BF_Model db = new BF_Model();

           IQueryable<vwAllExportLog> dsEDIReports_EF_vwAllExportLog;

           dsEDIReports_EF_vwAllExportLog = from c in db.vwAllExportLog
                                            let mydate2 = new DateTime(2014, 7, 17)
                                            where c.Production == true
                                                    && c.RunDate >= mydate2
                                            orderby c.CarName, c.CltName, c.RunDate
                                            select c;

           //provide local report information to viewer
           reportViewer1.Reset();
           reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = @"D:\Development\EDIReports_EF\EDIReports_EF\Reports\ExportsGroupedByCarrier.rdlc";
           reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

           reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("dsEDIReports_EF_vwAllExportLog", dsEDIReports_EF_vwAllExportLog));

           reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();

           //load report viewer
           reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: What is that last line there doing? As far as I know with report viewer, you only need to call reportviewer.LocalReport.Refresh() which you are already doing.  I don't even have a RefreshReport off of the viewer control.  Is that something custom that is being done?

Comment: The last line seems to be required.  The report does not render at all without it (the reportviewer remains blank).  I used an example I found on the internet as a guide, and unfortunately the examples out there don't go into why you need to do this or that.  I found I can do without the next to the last refresh but not the last.